# Audio not played after AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded

Tags: objective-c, ios9, avaudiosession

The issue is the following, when the user move his phone I speech a text.
When the audio is interrupted (call, whatsapp, etc) the interruption began/end is detected correctly but I'm not able to play anything after that.

I check with some NSLog and the only thing which doesn't work in the below code is when I try to set the session active again.
Also I tried with a dispatch because I read that the OS could take some times to allow my app to play anything, but the result is the same.
Error return by the setActive :  `AVAudioSession error activating: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=560557684`

Any clue ?

```
 - (void)handleAudioSessionInterruption:(NSNotification*)notification {
        NSNumber *interruptionType = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey];
        NSNumber *interruptionOption = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionKey];

        switch (interruptionType.unsignedIntegerValue) {
            case AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeBegan:{
                [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:nil];
                NSLog(@"AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeBegan");

            } break;
            case AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded:{
                NSLog(@"AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded");


                // • Make session active
                // • Update user interface
                // • AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionShouldResume option
                //[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error: nil];
                //self.speechSynthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
                dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    BOOL success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:nil];
                    NSLog(@"setActive NO :  %i" , success);

                    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:nil];
                    NSLog(@"setCategory %i" , success);

                    success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:nil];
                    NSLog(@"overrideOutputAudioPort %i" , success);


                    NSError *error;
            success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&error];
            if (!success) NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error activating: %@",error);


                    [self playSpeech:@"I speech a text" andVolume:1];


                });
            } break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"default :  interupt %lu",(unsigned long)interruptionType.unsignedIntegerValue);
                break;
        }
    }

    -(void)playSpeech:(NSString*)text andVolume:(float)volume {

        AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:text];
        utterance.volume = volume;
        utterance.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate;
        utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-UK"];
        [self.speechSynthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix this issue with the `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers` options